# .text() the parent class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change `.cartSubPrice` text to the new price provided by the JSON request. Everything else works perfectly even the total price change and I know it is returned because of firebug and just `alert(resultSub)` shows it. I just cant figure out how to tell it to go to the proper place and change. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jquery

```
$('.cartUpdate').bind("keyup", function() {
    changeItem = $(this);
    var url = 'cart/update' 
    var qty = $(this).attr('value');
    var rowid = $(this).attr('name');

    if(qty > 0) {
        $.post(url, {qty: qty, rowid: rowid }, function changeCost () {     

            $.getJSON('cart/updatePrice', {rowid: rowid}, function(data) {                  
                //convert to currency                                   
                resultSub = data.subTotal.toFixed(2);
                resultTotal = data.totalPrice.toFixed(2);           

                //change
                $(changeItem).parent('.cartSubPrice').text(resultSub);      
                $('.cartTotalPrice').text(resultTotal);


            });

        });
    }   

    return false;
});
```

Html

```
<div class="cartItem">
    Item 1
    <div class="cartSubPrice">80.00</div>    
    <input type="text" name="76ea881ebe188f1a7e7451a9d7f17ada" value="4" class="cartUpdate" >   
    <a href="#" id="cartDelete" name="76ea881ebe188f1a7e7451a9d7f17ada">x</a>
</div>
<div class="cartItem">
    Item 2
    <div class="cartSubPrice">20.00</div>    
    <input type="text" name="e7a36fadf2410205f0768da1b61156d9" value="1" class="cartUpdate" >   
    <a href="#" id="cartDelete" name="e7a36fadf2410205f0768da1b61156d9">x</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your "cartTotalPrice" class in html?

Comment: I think it should be $(changeItem).prev() instead of $(changeItem).parent() as .cartUpdate is a sibling of .cartSubPrice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
$(changeItem).parent('.cartSubPrice').text(resultSub);
```

By

```
$(changeItem).siblings('.cartSubPrice').text(resultSub);
```

Because, if I look at the html right you're trying to get an element in the same hierarchy, so if you have:

```
<element></element>
<parent>
      <child></child>
</parent> 

jQuery("child").parent(); //<parent></parent> 
jQuery("parent").siblings(); //[<element></element>]
```

Also, as 3nigma suggested if you want only the first element that matches the selector, you could use `.closest()`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation helped me a lot to understand why parent did not work. Still getting the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 $(changeItem).closest('.cartSubPrice').html(resultSub);      
 $(changeItem).val(resultTotal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
('.cartSubPrice').html(123); OR
('.cartSubPrice:eq(0)').html(123); OR
```

Comment: this will change html of ALL .cartSubPrice; but only the relevant .cartSubPrice should be updated (guessing you meant to use $ before the '(' )

Comment: of course it was bad copy from jsFiddle, thanks :) And of course my answer is wrong. I would use .closest like @Nicosunshine said.